# Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection when running functions in Algstat in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to use a package called Algstat in R.

```
library(algstat)
data(politics)
politics
countTables(politics)
```

But I always get the following error.

```
library(algstat)
data(politics)
politics
Party

Personality Democrat Republican
  Introvert        3          7
  Extrovert        6          4

countTables(politics)

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'numOfLatticePoints': No such file or directory
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Did you set Macaulay2 path with `setM2Path()`, Bertini path with `setBertiniPath()`, LattE-integrale path with `setLattePath()` and 4ti2 path with `setMarkovPath()`?

Comment: Thank your for your response. I tried, >setM2Path("/Users/****/Desktop/Macaulay2-1.8.2")
>setBertiniPath("/Users/****/Desktop/BertiniSource_v1.5")
>setLattePath("/Users/****/Desktop/latte")
>setMarkovPath("/Users/****/Desktop/latte-integrale-1.7.3/4ti2-1.6.3/test/markov")  But still gives me the same error. I have all these files on my desktop. Do you know why it is not working?